# How to compare 1st element of list of lists with another list and fill in the missing values with the 1st element of the list and zeros

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I compare 1st element of list of lists with another list and fill in the missing values with the 1st element of the list and zeros? For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [[1,7], [3,11], [5,16]]
new_list = [[1,7], [2,0], [3,11], [4,0], [5,16], [6,0]]
```

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `filter` to find the matching element from the other list.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [[1,7], [3,11], [5,16]]
new_list = [next(filter(lambda o: o[0] == x, list2), [x, 0]) for x in list1]
print(new_list)
```